# Is Drupal suitable for that kind of ecommerce?

Tags: 7, commerce, ubercart

I have to do website that sells webinars and I want to use D7 to this job. Unfortunately I have never done any Drupal ecommerce before.

I'll have to kind of users:

- Teacher
- Student

Payment method: PayPal only

Webinar content type:

- Title
- Description
- Start date (every webinar length is 60 minutes)
- Places
- Price is the same of all webinars and is specified by Admin
- Webinar booked at least 7 days before start costa less (discount and days limit  configurated via admin area)
- If a webinar is cancelled need option to move the participants/users into a new webinar

User of role Teacher can add/edit/list his Webinars.

In addition Teacher can create group with fields:

- Topic
- Description
  When Teacher is creating new webinar, he can specify group for this webinar (select list) (not mandatory)

Student (auth user) can buy single webinar or group. When buying group discount is bigger.

Every webinar can repeat and has multiple start date. Setting next start date must generate different ID for webinar for invoice

If do it by plain PHP database structure will look something like:

- groups

  - id
  - topic
  - title
- webinar

  - id
  - group_id
  - title
  - description
  - etc
- webinar_date

  - id
  - invoice_id (maybe webinar id + webinar_date id)
  - webinar_id
  - date

Teacher can see list of his webinar with dates, so if webinar has two dates it must be visible in two times in list. Also info about free places of webinar must be and income from bookings of webinar. After choosing webinar Teacher can see list of all users that buy webinar 'ticket'.

The same is for admin but he can see all webinars of course.

Is this possible to create in Drupal without a lot of pain?

Which module are most suitable for this: Commerce or Ubercart?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, most of which using Rules, Fields, Date and Views. I'd say that, due to the specificity around some features, Commerce would be best as it fully taps into the Entity API which makes developing a breeze.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but I'd say to go with Ubercart.

Commerce is promising but it lacks in additional modules, maturity and resources. Ubercart has been around for quite a long time so you can virtually find anything you need to do with it.

Also Ubercart is much less intimidating than Commerce for first-time users.

Just my 2 cents, hope this helps :)